# In "Looper" was there a reason why they didn't send people directly to the furnace?

Tags: time-travel, looper

In "Looper" the future bad-guys send back people to be killed in a field by a guy with a stupid gun who then takes them into what appears to be a massively-insecure blast-furnace equipped factory of some sort.

Why couldn't they just make the people appear inside the furnace in the first place?

Was there a reason given other than it would have made for a considerably shorter film?

Comment: The much better question would be why they need to send people back through time in the first place. They didn't have any problem kidnapping old Joe for example. They cannot tell me somebody could find him if they dissolve him into some large furnace right in the future. In the end they didn't have any problem killing his wife with a good old present gunshot. But Ok, that's just how the movie works.

Answer (score 14):

I think the intention is that it's a lot easier and cleaner to have someone on the other side there to make sure the victim is taken care of, rather than just popping them to a location that they'll die at.

Think about it this way.  Lets say that they did pop people into a furnace to kill them.  What happens if said furnace is down that day and the victim doesn't get killed?  Now they've got a royal mess on their hands.

Ok, so a man-made way to kill them doesn't work, lets pop them over some lava.  Can they do that?  Transport someone mid-air?  That doesn't seem likely as we always see them touching the ground when they appear, but we can't be sure of the laws.  OK, the bottom of the ocean?  Well that's submersing them in a non-air medium, which might not be possible.

So, out of all of the possibilites I can think of, transporting someone back to a known spot in time to be killed by someone seems the most logical, especially since you have someone back there governing everything.

Comment: To be clear, they transport people *through time*, not through space. In other words, if they were to send someone to the bottom of the ocean, they would have to build the time machine at the bottom of the ocean.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat They sent old Joe from future China to Kansas. How? Also, the Earth is rotating and flying through space every second, never in the same spot twice.

Comment: @Chloe You could be correct there. I don't recall off hand but I thought there was only one time machine? To be honest, it's probably not worth thinking about this, the sci-fi in Looper isn't particularly solid anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason Batman lived as long as he did; when no one is there to supervise the death, there's no way to be sure the death actually occurred.  Yes, I guess they could have someone sitting outside the blast furnace door peeking through a window to make sure the transport took place, but why bother?  Sticking them in a field and knowing they're gonna get popped with a shotgun is probably just as easy and much more easily confirmed.